# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'WEInvalidViewHierarchyException'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void) showPopUpFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    
    if (isIphone)
    {
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                                                inView:view
                              permittedArrowDirections:direction
                                              animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {

        if (isIOS8)
        {
            double delayInSeconds = 0.0;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                           {
                               [_popVC presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:direction animated:animated];
                           });
        }
        else
        {
            [_popVC presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:direction animated:animated];
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: In Xcode 10.3 and OS macOS Mojave 10.14.6 its working fine but when I m running same code in Xcode 11 and Mac OS 10.15 Catalina it giving me crash (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'WEInvalidViewHierarchyException', reason: 'The supplied view to present the popover from is not in the same view hierarchy as the parent view for the popover'). Please Help I tried a lot but nothing work . Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. You can edit your question, so it is better to put additional information in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Also, `UIPopoverController` is deprecated. You need to use `UIPopoverPresentationController` instead.

Comment: I have use WEPopoverController for Iphone.                                                        @property (nonatomic, retain) WEPopoverController *popoverController;

Comment: That library has not been updated for many years. You should really switch to the new API.

Comment: Is there any alternative for this code or I have change the library only?

Comment: There are many tutorials out there on how to use `UIPopoverPresentationController`.